# Dockerfile and GitHub Actions possible escape issue

Tags: bash, docker, escaping, github-actions

This line is in a Dockerfile which is built in a GitHub Actions ubuntu:latest runner.  The line below is being interpreted incorrectly.

`RUN echo "deb https://download:$SOME_VARIABLE@www.website.com/repo_apt buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/repo.list`

becomes

`RUN echo "deb ***www.website.com/repo_apt buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/repo.list`

The three asterisks are how GitHub Actions obscures secrets values.  So it looks like either Bash, GitHub Actions or the Docker build command is interpreting all of this - `deb https://download:$SOME_VARIABLE@` incorrectly as the variable, or the file is not correctly written in the first place.  I tried the commands manually though on a local, similar container and they do build the file normally.

This works correctly if I just paste in the variable rather than reference it.  Also I have overwritten the secret to make sure that it is correct.  It's a simple alphanumeric value.

At first we thought it might be an escape issue because of the //, but then why would the https: part also be obscured?

I've tried several different combinations of double and single quotes, three separate echo -n commands to the same file, escaping the // with // - // - /.  Several other things as well before realizing that the info was being interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: I technically got this working by adding a --build-arg for that variable in particular to the docker build command.  Other variables are working without this so it changed when I forced Docker to insert the variable rather than reading it from an ENV VAR with BASH.  I still need to solve this though as I may have to pass other secrets in the future and I'm actually just curious what I'm missing here.

Comment: `becomes` How do you check it?

Comment: How is this env variable set? In the workflow file?